# Displaying data through session in view in asp.net mvc3

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, invalidoperationexception

I am working on a ASP.net MVC project and want to display a particular users data which i get as a id through session.
According to that id I want to extract all data of particular employee.
for that I did this code:

My controller's Index method:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        object s = Session["EmployeeID"];
        var sessval = s.ToString();
        AdminDetailsModel model = new AdminDetailsModel();

        var data1 = (from e in db.Employees.Where(c => c.EmployeeID == sessval) join d in db.Designations on e.Designation1up equals d.Designation1up select new { EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID, FirstName = e.FirstName, LastName = e.LastName, DesignationInternal = d.DesignationInternal, DesignationExternal = d.DesignationExternal, OfficePhone = e.OfficePhone, CellPhone = e.CellPhone, JoiningDate = e.JoiningDate, EmailID = e.EmailID, Address = e.Address }).SingleOrDefault();

        return View(data1);
    }
```

I have created viewmodel for this in which i took all the methods which I need to display in view.

I have created view on this method which is strongly typed on my model class.
when I run it, I got error as:

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType1`10[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.DateTime,System.String,System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ResourceTracking.Employee'.
```

what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`select new {`

to

```
select new ResourceTracking.Employee {
```

You want to pass an instance of your `Employee` class to the view instead of an anonymous type.